# Complicated MS Access Greatest-N-Per-Group problem

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I am looking to combine the following queries into one, where

- scouting.jumpGate is integer,
- scouting.astroLoc is a string,
- scouting.ownerguild is a string and
- scouting.galaxy is a integer

that cross-links to another table (and is my GROUP):

```
    Select TOP 3 
        scouting.jumpGate, 
        scouting.astroLoc, 
        scouting.ownerGuild, 
        scouting.Galaxy 
FROM    scouting 
WHERE   scouting.Galaxy = 1 
AND     scouting.ownerGuild = 'TEST' 
ORDER BY    scouting.jumpGate DESC, 
            scouting.astroloc DESC;
```

and

```
    SELECT TOP 3 
        scouting.jumpGate, 
        scouting.astroLoc, 
        scouting.ownerGuild, 
        scouting.Galaxy 
FROM    scouting 
WHERE   scouting.Galaxy = 2 
AND     scouting.ownerGuild = 'TEST' 
ORDER BY    scouting.jumpGate DESC, 
            scouting.astroloc DESC;
```

and

```
    SELECT TOP 3 
        scouting.jumpGate, 
        scouting.astroLoc, 
        scouting.ownerGuild, 
        scouting.Galaxy 
FROM    scouting 
WHERE   scouting.Galaxy = 3 
AND     scouting.ownerGuild = 'TEST' 
ORDER BY    scouting.jumpGate DESC, 
            scouting.astroloc DESC;
```

continued until

```
    SELECT TOP 3 
        scouting.jumpGate, 
        scouting.astroLoc, 
        scouting.ownerGuild, 
        scouting.Galaxy 
FROM    scouting 
WHERE   scouting.Galaxy = 79 
AND     scouting.ownerGuild = 'TEST' 
ORDER BY    scouting.jumpGate DESC, 
            scouting.astroloc DESC;
```

The code I have generated after reading on Microsoft's website for this Greatest N Per Group problem is as follows:

```
Select  scouting.astroLoc, 
        scouting.galaxy, 
        scouting.jumpGate, 
        scouting.ownerGuild 
From    galaxy Inner Join 
        scouting On galaxy.[galaxy_ID] = scouting.galaxy 
Where   scouting.ownerGuild = 'SWARM' 
AND     (scouting.jumpGate) In (Select Top 3 scouting.jumpGate From scouting Where scouting.galaxy = galaxy.[galaxy_ID] Order By scouting.jumpGate Desc) 
Order By    scouting.astroLoc Desc, 
            scouting.jumpGate Desc
```

Basically, this is very close to what I would like. Everything seems to work. However, some of the GROUPS are not represented in the output even thought after eyeballing the data, each group has a record that satisfies the constraints of the query. Incidentally, if I take out the scouting.ownerGuild = 'SWARM' constraint, it works perfectly (but I need this constraint).

Comment: thanks for the edit - i tried myself but didn't know how to layout it out like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
Select  scouting.astroLoc, 
        scouting.galaxy, 
        scouting.jumpGate, 
        scouting.ownerGuild 
From    galaxy Inner Join 
        scouting On galaxy.[galaxy_ID] = scouting.galaxy 
WHERE   (scouting.ID) In (
             Select Top 3 scouting.ID
             From scouting 
             Where scouting.galaxy = galaxy.[galaxy_ID] 
             And scouting.ownerGuild = 'SWARM' 
             Order By scouting.jumpGate Desc) 
Order By    scouting.astroLoc Desc, 
                scouting.jumpGate Desc
```

Otherwise it seems likely that the top 3 may include some

```
  where scouting.ownerGuild <> 'SWARM'
```

Comment: I think I might have tried this constraint positions here too. Will let you know how I get on. Thanks!

Comment: By running the ownerGuild constraint here in this position within the query, it actually still returns values where scouting.ownerGuild = anything, any not just SWARM.

Comment: When I run the constraints in the position I placed it in within the question, I do indeed MISS some records, which is consistent with your point that "Otherwise it seems likely that the top 3 may include some  ...where scouting.ownerGuild <> 'SWARM'" - Although I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: no, it is not. the unique field in scouting tables is ID. jumpgate can be a tied value.

Comment: in place of scouting.jumpGate ?

Comment: Looks very promising. Will manually check this but looks to be working perfectly!

Comment: OK, this works great. Would you like to edit your answer accordingly and I'll tick it :) ?